# Ищу набор контролов, подобный Microsoft Office 2013

Tags: c#, .net, интерфейс, office, controls

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, пишем на .NET C# WPF - ищем компоненты, позволяющие организовать интерфейс, подобный Microsoft Office 2013. Есть, например, предложения от Actipro Ribbon, но существуют ли какие-нибудь бесплатные варианты? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff799534%28v=vs.110%29.aspx и здесь http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/ может то, что Вам нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Лента (Ribbon) есть в самом .Net

Это класс RibbonWindow из пространства System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon (в System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll)

Пример XAML

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfRibbon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Ribbon>
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Application Menu Item" />
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>                
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

        <RibbonTab Header="Tab1">
            <RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonButton x:Name="Button" Content="RibbonButton" Label="MyButton"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
        <RibbonTab Header="Tab2">
            <RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonButton x:Name="Button1" Content="RibbonButton" Label="MyButton"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>        
</Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```